# Ansible call variable inside a variable

Tags: jinja2, ansible

How would I call a variable inside a variable in Ansible

So I have the following

Meta > Main.yml

```
 - { role: core_nat_segment, foo: 'bar' }
```

Task > Main.yml

```
- name: Create resources for e-commerce services
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "{{aws_environment}}-yyy"
    state: "present"
    region: "{{aws_region}}"
    template: "xx
    template_parameters:
      ECSClusterName: "{{{{segment_name}}_private_stack.stack_outputs.PrivateCluster}}"
```

When i run the playbook I get the following error

```
fatal: [localhost] => Failed to template {{{{segment_name}}_private_stack.stack_outputs.PrivateCluster}}: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'
```

The output im expecting is

```
bar_private_stack.stack.stack_outputs.PrivateCluster
```

Any help pointers would be much appreciated.